# Trip Day Problem

Tags: problem-solving

I have a question as a problem.

Jack has gone to a trip and come back and when his friend asked the weather during Jack's trip, he answered as;

- There were $10$ days which morning was sunny.
- There were $7$ days which afternoon was sunny.
- When afternoon was rainy, morning was sunny.
- It rained totally $15$ times on morning or on afternoon.

So how many days did Jack spend for his trip according to information above?

I found the answer is 16. The answer on the book says 17. Thats why i confused.
Thank you.

Comment: Are we to assume sunny and rainy are the only two options?

Comment: Must the weather be sunny or rainy? Or may it be foggy or snowy?

Comment: Yes they are two options. Just rainy or sunny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints: Consider the four sets:

$SS$, $SR$, $RS$, and $RR$ ($SR$ means sunny in the morning and rainy in the afternoon).

From the given information, you know that

- $|SS|+|SR|=10$ because $10$ days were sunny in the morning.
- $|SS|+|RS|=7$ because on $7$ days, the afternoon was sunny.
- $|RR|=0$ because if it were rainy in the afternoon, then it would have to be sunny in the morning.
- $|SR|+|RS|+2|RR|=15$ because it rained on $15$ days.

From this, can you figure out the total number of days: $|SS|+|SR|+|RS|+|RR|$?

Comment: I found also 16. The answer on the book says 17. Thats why i confused. Do you agree with me?

Comment: This would be good to add your original question.  I think that $16$ also works.

Comment: Don't forget if it rained in the morning and afternoon that is 2 times it rained by only 1 day.  I get 17.  S that last line should be |sr| + |rs| + 2|rr| = 15.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for the catch.  However, from the way that the question was worded, $|RR|=0$, so it doesn't make a difference!

Comment: Oops.  That was an error I made. Somehow I got that |RS| was 0.  Not |RR|.  If so, you get that |SS| = 7,|SR| = 3, and |RR| = 6 and ... dang, that'd still be 16.  Okay, not sure why I made those two mistakes.

Comment: The only issue is that, perhaps, we're misinterpreting the condition "When afternoon was rainy, morning was sunny." and that's how the answer is $17$.

Comment: For which interpretation of that condition, can the solution be 17, do you think?

Comment: I can find no reasonable interpretation that leads to $17$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that rainy and sunny are the only to options we have:

$X =$ number of all sunny days

$Y = $ number of sunny mornings, rainy afternoons

$Z = $ number of all rainy days.

$A = $ number of rainy mornings and sunny afternoons.

There were 10 days which morning was sunny $\implies X + Y = 10$

There were 7 days which afternoon was sunny $\implies X + A = 7$

When afternoon was rainy, morning was sunny $\implies Z = 0$

It rained totally 15 times on morning or on afternoon $\implies Y + A + 2Z = 15$

Solve for $X + Y + Z + A$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r$ and $s$ be the number of rainy and sunny *mornings*, respectively, and likewise let $R$ and $S$ be the number of rainy and sunny *afternoons*.  Clearly $r+s=R+S$, since each side counts the total number of *days* in the trip, which is the number we're after.

The first two bullet points tell us $s=10$ and $S=7$.  The final two bullet points tell us $r+R=15$.  (That is, it can't rain both morning and afternoon, so the total number of days with rain is $r+R$.)  This gives us enough to solve for $r$ and $R$:  From $r+10=R+7$ we have $R=r+3$, which gives us $2r+3=15$, hence $r=(15-3)/2=6$ and $R=6+3=9$.  And thus the total number of days in the trip is $6+10=9+7=16$.

I don't see any way to interpret the problem so as to get $17$ as the answer.  The book seems to have made a mistake.

Comment: Thank you Barry Cipra. I was thinking that third condition means that if afternoon is rainy, the next morning will be sunny?

Comment: @layout789, Hmm, interesting interpretation.  I don't think it can get you to $17$ though.  (Note, all three answers so far interpret the third condition in the same way.)

Comment: I know that I am forcing a little.